# Shared Calendars from Office365

Tags: calendars

I can't seem to access other calenders from my Office365 organisation on my Windows Phone 8. I was previously able to do this with Google Apps.

I've searched the web and on here, but can't find any how to do it - The MS sales page indicates it's possible. http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/business/office-365-business-email-and-shared-calendar-services-FX102996755.aspx.

I may be missing something incredibly obvious, but I can't see it at the moment!

Comment: Is the account added as an Exchange account?

Comment: Yes, it shows as an 'Outlook' icon. Syncs my own calendar, tasks, email and contacts perfectly. Server is outlook.office365.com if that makes any difference.

Comment: @Mark how is it going for you?

Comment: @MikaelDúiBolinder I gave up on it! I don't think it can be done using the standard apps. Hopefully they'll upgrade them in the future.

Comment: @Mark Are you able to see the calendar using the desktop version of Outlook? Are you sure that it is an Exchange calendar and not a SharePoint one?

Comment: Yes - I can open in Outlook fine. It's another O365 user I'm trying to view.

Comment: Is there any update on it?

Answer (score 1):

We have a shared mailbox in addition to my own mailbox in office365. I added the shared mailbox as a second email+account exchange account to my phone. In the account settings I selected to sync the calendar and in the calendar app settings selected to display that calendar. Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks @Robin, unfortunately that would mean users sharing passwords with each other, so it's not a viable workaround for us.

Comment: I found [this](http://community.office365.com/en-us/f/158/t/48291.aspx) post which suggests it still cannot be done however someone has created a paid for [app](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/opencal/317a469f-9f9e-4047-ac32-92e8b46d0b8c) as one solution